# Authorize.net ARB API, E-mail Questions

Tags: authorize.net

Just had a few simple questions on the **Authorize.net Automated Recurring Billing**

- Does the API allow you to **manage subscriptions remotely**?

  - An example would be updating subscriptions and **searching** through them through the API and editing any info you see fit?
- Can you modify the **automated emails** to look **personalized**?
- Can you **pro-rate**, or do you need to set it up through AIM (Advanced Integration Method) for the initial transaction and with the AVS (Address Verification Service) for validity?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the API allow you to manage subscriptions remotely? An example would be updating subscriptions and searching through them through the API and editing any info you see fit?

You can update subscriptions after they are created. The ARBUpdateSubscriptRequest API call allows for this. You should refer to the API guide to see what you can and cannot do with it.

> Can you modify the automated emails to look personalized?

No. If you want to have personalize emails you will need to send your own.

> Can you pro-rate, or do you need to set it up through AIM (Advanced Integration Method) for the initial transaction and with the AVS (Address Verification Service) for validity?

You should always do the first payment through AIM to verify the payment goes through and the credit is valid anyway so if pro-rating a payment is necessary it's easily handled during this step.